# If I catch exceptions inside a using statement for a SqlConnection, does the using still handle closing and disposing my connection?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, idisposable

I'm going through some old C#.NET code in an ASP.NET application making sure that all **SqlConnections** are wrapped in **using** blocks.

This piece of code used to open **cn** and **da** and close and dispose them in both the **catch** block and the end of the method. I added the **usings** and can't figure out for certain if the **using** blocks still handle disposing of the connection if an exception is thrown in the **try** and caught in the **catch**. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220234/intercepting-an-exception-inside-idisposable-dispose) seems to suggest that it does.

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Global.sDSN))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        // do some stuff
        try
        {
            // do stuff that might throw exceptions
        }
        catch (catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            //return something here
            // can I ditch these because the using's handle it?      
            da.Dispose();
            cn.Close();
            cn.Dispose();
            return msg;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they will. They're basically turned into a `finally` block.

So something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Global.sDSN))
{
....
}
```

is really turned into:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Global.sDSN)
try
{
....
}
finally
{
    cn.Dispose();
}
```

more or less - and the finally block is **always** executed, no matter what might have happened before in the `try {.....}`  block.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `using` clause this is what's happening:

```
myobject = new object();
try{ 
   // do something with myobject
}finally{
   myobject.Dispose();
}
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.